# Getting Error on Synpatic Package Manager, UbuntuTweak on the Repository and Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: unity, repository, synaptic, ubuntu-tweak

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix this “E:Type '*' is not known on line * in source list …” update error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/96967/how-do-i-fix-this-etype-is-not-known-on-line-in-source-list-update)

Everytime I tried to open Synpatic Package Manger I get this:

> E: Type 'ain' is not known on line 3
>   in source list
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/the-board-team-dev-snapshots-natty.list
>   E: The list of sources could not be
>   read. Go to the repository dialog to
>   correct the problem. E: _cache->open()
>   failed, please report.

I removed the 
`the-board-team-dev-snapshots-natty`
from Ubuntu Software Center but still get the same error

> UbuntuTweak: E: Type 'ain' is not
>   known on line 1 in source list
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/the-board-team-dev-snapshots-natty.list
>   E: Unable to lock the list directory
>
> UbuntuSoftwareCenter: E:Type 'ain' is
>   not known on line 1 in source list
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/the-board-team-dev-snapshots-natty.list